# template class conversion with two parameters

Tags: c++, class, templates

I'm having problems converting a template class of the same typename but just with another size to the same template class. Let me explain this by code:

```
template<typename T, int SIZE>
class Array
{
  T aData[SIZE];
  friend Array operator+(Array &arr1, Array &arr2);
};
```

This is what I have as the template class. Lets assume I already overloaded `operator+`.

So this is what I want to do:

```
Array<double, 10> a1;
Array<double, 20> a2;
a1 + a2;
```

I know that `a1` and `a2` are different classes. So my question is, how can I convert `a2` to `Array<double, 10>`? I would want to do this with a constructor, which takes an object of `Array<T, SIZE2>` and return object of `Array<T, SIZE>`. Is this doable?
In more general terms: I want to convert `Array<T, SIZE2>` to a class of `Array<T, SIZE>`.

Comment: what would it mean to convert a `Array<double,20>` to a `Array<double,10>` ? You either loose information of have to fill the blanks when the arrays are not of same size. If thats what you really want to do you need to explain how such conversion should work

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution is to make `operator +` a template that can handle two arguments of different type.

```
#include <cstddef>

template
<
    typename x_Item
,   ::std::size_t x_size
>
class Array;

template
<
    typename x_Item
,   ::std::size_t x_left_size
,   ::std::size_t x_right_size
>
Array<x_Item, x_left_size + x_right_size>
operator +
(
    Array<x_Item, x_left_size> const & left
,   Array<x_Item, x_right_size> const & right
);

template
<
    typename x_Item
,   ::std::size_t x_size
>
class Array
{
    template
    <
        ::std::size_t x_left_size
    ,   ::std::size_t x_right_size
    >
    friend
    Array<x_Item, x_left_size + x_right_size>
    operator +
    (
        Array<x_Item, x_left_size> const & left
    ,   Array<x_Item, x_right_size> const & right
    );

    x_Item aData[x_size];
};


template
<
    typename x_Item
,   ::std::size_t x_left_size
,   ::std::size_t x_right_size
>
Array<x_Item, x_left_size + x_right_size>
operator +
(
    Array<x_Item, x_left_size> const & left
,   Array<x_Item, x_right_size> const & right
)
{
    // implementation...
}
```

Comment: isn't there a way to overload `operator+` once and just convert the object to my desired type, so I can add them together?

Comment: @auroNpls You can certainly implement a template constructor accepting array of different size for this purpose. However it seems wasteful to create temporary array argument here.

Comment: well that's what I'm trying to achieve here. Any ideas here? I would really appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

One way is to provide conversion constructor:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t SIZE>
class Array
{
public:

    Array() = default;
    Array(const Array&) = default;
    Array(Array&&) = default;
    
    template <std::size_t N>
    Array(const Array<T, N>&) requires (SIZE < N)  { /*..*/ }

    friend Array operator+(const Array &arr1, const Array &arr2) { /*..*/ }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34125c649330d627)

- `requires` is C++20, you might use SFINAE tricks before.
- You have to take care of expected conversion to avoid ambiguity:
  (Do you want `a1 + a2` to resolve to `static_cast<decltype(a2)>(a1) + a2` or `a1 + static_cast<decltype(a1)>(a2)`?)